# Writing $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ as central extension of $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ by $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, exact-sequence, semidirect-product

I would like to prove that $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$, where $p$ is prime, can be constructed as a central extension of $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ by $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$.

 So I need
$$0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z_p} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{p} \rightarrow 0$$
I am not sure how to show that this sequence is short exact.

 Also, can $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ be written as a semidirect product?

Comment: To show the sequence is exact, you need to specify the morphisms in question. Until you do, there is no way to prove it.

Comment: No, it can’t be a nontrivial semidirect product. Since it is abelian, if it were a semidirect product then it would be a direct product, but $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ is indecomposable. Alternatively, $\mathbb{Z}_p\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_p$ would necessarily contain at least *two* distinct subgroups of order $p$, but a cyclic group contains a unique subgroup of any order that divides the order of the group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to label your maps. We'd like to find $f$ and $g$ that turn the sequence below into a central extension:
$$0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p \xrightarrow{f} \mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \xrightarrow{g} \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0$$
Since $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ is abelian, we know that $Im(f)\subset Z(\mathbb{Z}_{p^2})$ for any group homomorphism $f$. So really, to show that it's a [central extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension#Central_extension), we just need to find $f$ and $g$ so that the sequence is exact.

I don't want to give the answer away, but note that $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Can you see what this subgroup would be? Once you've found it, again note that the ambient group is abelian, so all subgroups are normal. This might cause you to think about quotient maps.

See Arturo's comment for the question about whether this can be realized as a semidirect product.

Comment: Since $\mathbb{Z}_n$ means, in this context, “the integers modulo $n$”, presumably you mean that $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ contains a subgroup *isomorphic* to $\mathbb{Z}_p$, not that it contains the literal subgroup $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: Fair. I was playing a little loose with the terminology. I'll edit the answer.